# Fetching the friendlist on Facebook not using an API - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the list of my friends on Facebook that are not using an application. I know this is possible because it's been done in the Hackbook. However, after mind-boggling research  on Facebook Developer documentation and the code for Hackbook, I am not able to find any particular way to go ahead. Any hint or help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access `/me/friends?fields=installed` with your user's access token.
Any of their friends who also use your app will have an 'installed: true' entry in the response

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems the possible answer to the problem, however, I'll get back to you after trying it out.
Thanks a million!